# Load chart components dynamically in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have created a number of reusable chart components in Angular 4. All the data to draw a chart coming from a REST api. When I am loading the parent component I will get the data for the list of charts in the following format.

```
[
   {
      "chartId":1,
      "chartType":"Bar"
   },
   {
      "chartId":2,
      "chartType":"Pie"
   }
]
```

I am using attribute selector for the chart components. For example,

```
<div app-bar-chart></div>
```

What I want to do is, I need to iterate through the chart list JSON and according to the 'chartType' I need to set the attribute. For example if 'chartType' is 'Pie' then the element should be,

```
<div app-pie-chart></div>
```

How can I implement this? Thank you.

Comment: hey, did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attribute but you will not get the component initiated there.

Here is how you can do it. Create a JSON that contains the reference to the component class, not the string:

```
export class BarComponent {...}
export class PieComponent {...}

...

const components = [
    {
        "chartId": 1,
        "chartType": BarComponent < ---component class reference
    },
    {
        "chartId": 2,
        "chartType": PieComponent
    }
]
```

Then use [NgComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) to render these components:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let c of components">
     <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="c"></ng-container>
```

Read these articles for more information:

- [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet)
- [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)